# URL redirection in stormcrawler renders the crawl for that page in error state

Tags: stormcrawler

I'm trying to crawl a url which looks something like: https://something.com/forums.
The status index in storm crawler initially sets the record to "Redirection" state, and the new redirected url to be discovered goes into "Error" state with a message like error source - content filtering.

Could anyone help me troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 0):

the fact that it comes from a redirection is not relevant. The target URL gets fetched but something is happening while running the parse filters

https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/b19bf717fe8a9e4d289ec06c00530c05a1392670/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/bolt/JSoupParserBolt.java#L352

Can you please look at the logs and see if you can find a related message?

**PS**: have just added [a new utility](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/794) to debug parse filters. Checkout SC from master, build it and change the dependency in your project to 1.17-SNAPSHOT, you should then be able to test the parse filters on the URL.